# How to parse INT values in brackets

Tags: c#

How can I parse the INT contents of this string, and add to List ?

```
Files[file1.jpg[2066654],file2.png[234235],file3.gif[56476788]]
```

That way I can call fields, like list.Filename, list.Filesize

Its a custom string im using to group files in a txt file, so I want to extract these values out : filename (with extension), and size (int)

How can I do this? I've tried

```
var filename = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('Files[') + 1).str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(']'));
```

But I have no way of getting this especially in this type of format. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the format of your string? Have you considered using a more standard text format, such as JSON, with better support for parsing?

Comment: I am developing my own string format in my own files for a application. JSON however is much easier to work with by far.

Comment: `str.Substring(...).str` isn't going to compile; did you mean `+ str` instead of `.str`?  What that would do, though, is take everything after the last `File[` and concatenate it with everything after the last `]`; everything after the last `]` would be duplicated in the result.  Instead, you'd need one call to `Substring()` that retrieves everything _between_ `Files[` and `]` and then parse/`Split()` the contents from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is your friend here.

Try this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^Files\[((?'name'(.*?))\[(?'length'(\d+))\],?)*\]$");

var input = "Files[file1.jpg[2066654],file2.png[234235],file3.gif[56476788]]";

var match = regex.Match(input);
var names = match.Groups["name"].Captures.Cast<Capture>();
var lengths = match.Groups["length"].Captures.Cast<Capture>();

var output =
    names
        .Zip(lengths, (f, n) => new
        {
            file = f.Value,
            length = int.Parse(n.Value)
        })
        .ToArray();
```

That gives me:

| file | length |
| --- | --- |
| file1.jpg | 2066654 |
| file2.png | 234235 |
| file3.gif | 56476788 |

Comment: If the author is struggling with the logic of `Substring()` then I think some explanation of what this is doing would be necessary.  Also, that expression will match `Files[file1.jpg[2066654]file2.png[234235]file3.gif[56476788]]` (commas omitted) as three files, too.

Comment: Of course its 3 files, that was the example I provided as a template. Anyone who reviews the OP will know this, however thanks for extended clarification. Give the man my vote back lol